# Difference between " to apprise" and "to impart"

Tags: word-difference

When I look up the word "[inform](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inform)" and check out its synonyms, I can see that the words [apprise](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/apprise) and [impart](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/impart) are listed as a synonym of it, besides more informal words such as tell and communicate.

However, neither the word apprise nor the word impart is  shown as synonyms of each other on the Oxford Dictionary, when I looked them up one by one. I am cognizant of they are formal words, however especially for this reason I would like to use them correctly in my writings.

Therefore,this made me enquire concerning the difference between them in terms of meaning.

Answer (score 1):

To

> **apprise**

is to *update* someone,

> keeping them **apprised** of the changing situation.

To

> **impart**

is to *give* someone information,

> He **imparted** his knowledge of mathematics to his students.

The knowledge is not changing.

Both *impart* and *apprise* are a *transfer of information*.

Comment: You apprise somebody **of** something, but you impart something **to** somebody.

Comment: Apprise might be in the dictionary. It might mean what you want to say. It sounds really old-fashioned to me ( and I am not young!). So, use it with care.